# Preserving Scope in ng-repeat ( not wanting child scope )

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularfire

I might be missing something conceptually but I understand that ng-repeat creates child scopes but for my scenario this is undesirable.  Here is the scenario.  I have a 3way bind to a firebase dataset.  The object is an object with n sub objects.  In my current code structure I use ng-repeat to iterate and render these objects with a custom directive.  The issue is that these objects are meant to be "live" ( meaning that they are 3-way bound.  The highest level object is bound with angularfire $bind ).

So the simple scenario in my case would be where the ng-repeat created scope was not isolated from the scope that it was created from.

I am looking for ideas on how to do this?  Or suggestions on other approaches.

Comment: I think you missing the part of `$watch`. `ng-repeat` must create a child (non isolated) scope for each item. Maybe share with us some code and show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be a complete answer, but I can help with the angularFire portion, and probably an angular guru can fill in the blanks for you (see //todo).

First of all, don't try to share scope. Simple pass the variables you want into the child scope. Since you'll want a 3-way binding, you can use `&` to call a method on the parent scope.

For example, to set up this pattern:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,widget) in widgets">
    <data-widget bound-widget="getBoundWidget(key)"/>
</div>
```

You could set up your directive like this:

```
.directive('dataWidget', function() {
   return {
      scope: {
         boundWidget: '&boundWidget'
      },

      /* your directive here */

      //todo presumably you want to use controller: ... here

   }
});
```

Where &boundWidget invokes a method in the parent $scope like so:

```
.controller('ParentController', function($scope, $firebase) {
    $scope.widgets = $firebase(/*...*/);
    $scope.getBoundWidget = function(key) {
        var ref = $scope.widgets.$child( key );
        // todo, reference $scope.boundWidget in the directive??
        ref.$bind(/*** ??? ***/);
    };
});
```

Now you just need someone to fill in the //todo parts!

Answer (score 0):

You still have access to the parent scope in the repeat. You just have to use $parent.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.someParentScopeVariable = 'Blah'
      $scope.data = [];
      $scope.data.push({name:"fred"});
      $scope.data.push({name:"frank"});
      $scope.data.push({name:"flo"});
      $scope.data.push({name:"francis"});
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | filter: search">
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.someParentScopeVariable"/>
              <input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nn8Pc2VglufgqvXX2cQB?p=preview)